# Switch back to startup window when successful

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm still beginner.
How do I do it, who the image, and the text has been successfully uploaded that it changes to the TableView?

```
 @IBAction func postImage(_ sender: Any) {

    if let image = imageTopost.image {


        let post = PFObject(className: "Post")

        post["message"] = comment.text

        post["userId"] = PFUser.current()?.objectId

        if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image){


            let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()


            let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)
            post["imageFile"] = imageFile
            post.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in


                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()


                if success {
                    self.displayAlert(title: "Hat super geklappt", message: "Dein Ziel wurde erfolgreich hinzugefügt")
                    self.comment.text = ""
                    self.imageTopost.image = nil

                }else {

                    self.displayAlert(title: "Etwas ist schiefgelaufen" , message: "Dein Bild konnte leider nicht gespeichert werden. Versuche es nochmal. Dein Internet muss eingeschalten sein." )
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I think that I here is the code. Have but unfortunately no idea how I make this must

```
              if success {
                    self.displayAlert(title: "Hat super geklappt", message: "Dein Ziel wurde erfolgreich hinzugefügt")
                    self.comment.text = ""
                    self.imageTopost.image = nil

                }else {

                    self.displayAlert(title: "Etwas ist schiefgelaufen" , message: "Dein Bild konnte leider nicht gespeichert werden. Versuche es nochmal. Dein Internet muss eingeschalten sein." )
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: What is your question actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to change the root VC

```
let homeView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView")
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeView!)
nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav
```

Comment: Thank you very much this will try